# How do I search a file for certain lines and then extract only certain sections of that line in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, search

So I have a text file that is a server report and has about 1000 lines of information in it. I'm trying to write a script that can search the report for only certain pieces of information I'm looking for. For example:

> Server 1 Health Check
>
> Date - Count of errors
>
> ---
>
> **06/25/15** : **14**
>
> **6/24/15** :  **21**
>
> **6/23/15** :  **17**
>
> **6/24/15** :  **33**
>
> Server 2 Health Check
>
> Date   -   Count of errors
>
> ---
>
> **06/25/15** : **4**
>
> **6/24/15** :  **13**
>
> **6/23/15** :  **21**
>
> **6/24/15** :  **33**
>
> Errors caused by X
>
> ---
>
> Server 1:
>
> **32**
>
> Server 2:
>
> **24**

The three sections are "Server Health Check 1", "Server Health Check 2", and "Errors caused by x." The data from each section that i need extracted is in bold. Does anyone know how i could go about doing this?

Comment: If you have *no idea at all* where to start then you should take a Perl course or hire a software engineer. Otherwise you should write a Perl program using your best guess and ask questions if you can't get it working

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                     

use warnings;
use strict;

use constant SECTION_HEALTH_CHECK => 'Health Check';
use constant SECTION_ERRORS       => 'Errors caused by X';
use constant RE_HEALTH_CHECK_DATA => qr|^(\d+/\d+/\d+)\s+:\s+(\d+)|; # Date, Count      
use constant RE_ERRORS_DATA       => qr|^(\d+)|;                     # Count            
use constant FMT_DATE             => '%02d-%02d-%02d';

open my $fh, 'foo.txt'
or die "Unable to open 'foo.txt' : $!";  # CHANGEME                                 

my ($section, %errors_by_date, %errors_caused_by_server);
my $server = 0;

# Read through the file, line by line                                                   
while (<$fh>) {
    next unless m|\S|; # Skip empty / whitespace only lines                             
    $section =
        m|${\SECTION_HEALTH_CHECK}| ? SECTION_HEALTH_CHECK
      : m|${\SECTION_ERRORS}|       ? SECTION_ERRORS
      :                               $section;

    if (m|Server (\d+)|) {
        $server = $1;
    }

    if (SECTION_HEALTH_CHECK eq $section
        and $_ =~ RE_HEALTH_CHECK_DATA) {
        my ($date, $count) = ($1, $2);
        $errors_by_date{ $server }->{ date_to_yymmdd($date) } += $count;
    }

    if (SECTION_ERRORS eq $section
        and $_ =~ RE_ERRORS_DATA) {
        my ($count) = $1;
        $errors_caused_by_server{ $server } += $count;
    }
}

for my $server_id (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %errors_by_date) {
    print "\n--- Server $server_id ---\n\n";
    for my $date (sort keys $errors_by_date{$server_id}) {
        my $count = $errors_by_date{$server_id}->{$date};
        my $normal_date = yymmdd_to_date($date);
        print "On $normal_date there were $count errors!\n";
    }
    my $errors_count = $errors_caused_by_server{$server_id} // 0;
    next unless $errors_count;
    print "\nThere were $errors_count errors caused by this server!\n";
}

sub date_to_yymmdd {
    my ($date) = @_;
    my ($mm,$dd,$yy) = split '/', $date;
    return sprintf(FMT_DATE,$yy,$mm,$dd);
}

sub yymmdd_to_date {
    my ($date) = @_;
    my ($yy,$mm,$dd) = split '-', $date;
    return sprintf(FMT_DATE,$mm,$dd,$yy);
}

1;
```

which outputs the following:

```
--- Server 1 ---

On 06-23-15 there were 17 errors!
On 06-24-15 there were 54 errors!
On 06-25-15 there were 14 errors!

There were 32 errors caused by this server!

--- Server 2 ---

On 06-23-15 there were 21 errors!
On 06-24-15 there were 46 errors!
On 06-25-15 there were 4 errors!

There were 24 errors caused by this server!
```